# Ways to avoid that for-loop variables cut into Python's global namespace

Tags: python, for-loop, namespaces, scope

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid that for-loop variables cut into Python's global namespace?

The only solution I could come up with so far would be using closures, such as list comprehensions

E.g., for the following code:

```
i = 1
print([i for i in range(5)])
print(i, 'i in global')

j = 1
for j in range(5):
    if j == 4:
        print(j, 'j in for-loop')
print(j, 'j in global')
```

prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1 i in global
4 j in for-loop
4 j in global
```

EDIT:
I assume that the for-loop namespace falls into the categoy "Global", unlike a function ("Local") in the LEGB rule, and thus there might be no solution to that? Btw., do Python 2.x comprehensions do not have their own namespace? since it was pointed out in the comments that Python 2.x would print "`4 in global`" ( I am using Python 3.4)

Comment: It says `4 i in global` for me. But then again I'm on Python2x. Anyone know why?

Comment: Oh, really? I was using Python 3.4, that's weird

Comment: Yes. That I assumed from the `print` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` loops don't have their own scope in Python; there is only *surrounding* scope. So any variable defined in the `for` expression will persist in that scope. They're only being added into the global scope because you're running your code outside of a function. If you add it into a function, you'll see it doesn't "leak":

```
def loop():
    for j in range(5):
        pass

>>> loop()
>>> 'j' in globals()
False
```

In Python 2.x, list comprehensions had the exact same behaviour: they would add the iterated variable into the local scope, as they were fundamentally syntactic sugar for the `for` construct. As this seemed to continually surprise people, it was changed for Python 3.x so that the variables aren't added to the local scope.

> Also note that list comprehensions have different semantics: they are closer to syntactic sugar for a generator expression inside a list() constructor, and in particular the loop control variables are no longer leaked into the surrounding scope.

[What's New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax)

The scope behaviour of `for` loops is useful for patterns like the following:

```
# find line number in file with matching text
for i, line in enumerate(some_file):
    if 'some text' in line:
        break
print('First match found at line {}.'.format(i))
```

Comment: So that means for-loops only have their own namespace, and if they are completed, the namespace is deleted, but if the same variable name is already defined in one global namespace, it overwrites it?

Comment: @SebastianRaschka Not at all. `for` loops don't have their own namespace, they have the namespace of the scope they exist in. In a module, that's module/global level. In a function, that's local level. A `for` loop will _always_ leave their variable defined in the existing scope, and will _always_ rebind any existing variable to their value. I've added an example above to explain why this is useful.

Comment: arg, had a stupid copy and past error where i forgot to change one of the variable names... therefore this misconception about for-loops having their own namespaces, sry, it's all clear now. Thanks for the patience ;)