# Loop Variables Overwrite Globals

Tags: python, namespaces

In python, why do loop variables overwrite already defined global variables? It seems counterintuitive that a loop variable is put into the module's global namespace rather than a new local namespace just for the loop. Here's an example that shows what I'm talking about:

```
c = 3.14

print("before loop c = {}".format(c))
for c in range(3):
    print("in loop c = {}".format(c))
print("after loop c = {}".format(c))
```

Running this code will print out:

```
before loop c = 3.14
in loop c = 0
in loop c = 1
in loop c = 2
after loop c = 2
```

Reusing names like this is almost definitely bad coding style, but it may happen accidentally in large modules and cause globals to be defined where you don't expect them to be. For example if I were to do this:

```
def f(x):
     print("x is {}".format(c)) # finger slipped, wrote c instead of x

for c in range(3):
    print("c is {}".format(c))

for a in "test":
    f(a)
```

I would get:

```
c is 0
c is 1
c is 2
x is 2
x is 2
x is 2
x is 2
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377182/ways-to-avoid-that-for-loop-variables-cut-into-pythons-global-namespace) seems to indicate that for loops don't have their own namespace by design. What is the rationale behind this when it can cause bugs depending on when loops are run relative to the execution order of the program?

Comment: I don't have any sources for the rationale, and I think it was made a very long time ago.  But my impression it's less a decision of "let's not give loops their own scope" than "let's not give *anything* its own scope unless it absolutely needs it".  So the *only* things that have their own scope are classes and functions.  An advantage is that it reduces the number of different kinds of assignment; the assignment that takes place in `for x in blah` has exactly the same semantics as doing `x = stuff` at that point in the code.

Comment: unfortunately i dont think stackoverflow will give you a good reason behind the decision ... this is probably a question more suited to something like quora

Comment: It's no more a source of bugs than is something like `c=1; print c; c=2` vs. `c=1; c=2; print c`. Statements (including `for` loops) are executed sequentially, with no reordering.

Comment: Existing discussion on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/27yt3y/why_does_python_lack_nested_scopes_a_la_blocks_in/. [This article](http://python-history.blogspot.de/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html) from GvR hints that there may be performance reasons, too.