# confused with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

After the first for loop, my dictionary shrunk and I am left with only one key value pair at the end of the for loop as can be seen in the results. and at the end somehow it gives the string error. Can anyone suggest what am i not understanding about dictionaries?

```
states = {
           'Bagmati' : 'BG',
           'Gandaki' : 'GD',
           'Karnali' : 'KL',
           'Janakpur' : "JK",
           'Mechi' : 'MC'
           }

cities = {
            'BG' : 'Kathmandu',
            "GD" : "Pokhara",
            "KL" : "Jumla",
            "MC" : 'Jhapa'
            }
            

cities['BG'] = 'Hetauda'
cities['MC'] = 'Taplejung'
cities['BG'] = 'Ramechap'
cities['JK'] = 'Dhanusha'

print(f'1. {states}')

for states, abbrev in list(states.items()):
    print(f'the {states} is abbreviated as {abbrev}')
print(states)
print(cities)    
#print every city and states
for abbrev, cities in list(cities.items()):
    print(f'the {abbrev} state has {cities} city')
print(f'2. {states}')
print(f'3. {cities}')
# now lets access both the states and cities dictionaries
for states, abbrev in list(state`enter code here`s.items()):
    print(f' the {states} state is abbreviated as {abbrev}')
    print(f' and has the city {cities[abbrev]}')
```

Results:

```
C:\Users\Prabin\Desktop\Desktop\personal-projects\mystuff\39. Dictionaries>python new12.py
1. {'Bagmati': 'BG', 'Gandaki': 'GD', 'Karnali': 'KL', 'Janakpur': 'JK', 'Mechi': 'MC'}
the Bagmati is abbreviated as BG
the Gandaki is abbreviated as GD
the Karnali is abbreviated as KL
the Janakpur is abbreviated as JK
the Mechi is abbreviated as MC
Mechi
{'BG': 'Ramechap', 'GD': 'Pokhara', 'KL': 'Jumla', 'MC': 'Taplejung', 'JK': 'Dhanusha'}
the BG state has Ramechap city
the GD state has Pokhara city
the KL state has Jumla city
the MC state has Taplejung city
the JK state has Dhanusha city
2. Mechi
3. Dhanusha
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new12.py", line 36, in <module>
    for states, abbrev in list(states.items()):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Because you are re-using the variable `states`: `for states, abbrev in list(states.items()):` so your dictionary gets replaces by the string. Note, don't do `list(states.items())` you can just use `states.items()`. Same thing for `for abbrev, cities in list(cities.items())`

Comment: what is `state'enter code here's.items`?

Comment: Basically: pick loop variable names that don't conflict with block var names. Python variables work on function scope, not block scope so it overwrites the dict in the block outside of the loop. A [mcve] would be: `a = 42; for a in range(1): pass; print(a)` => `0`.

Comment: See [loop variables overwrite globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544391/loop-variables-overwrite-globals) and [ways to avoid for loop variables cut into Python's global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377182/ways-to-avoid-that-for-loop-variables-cut-into-pythons-global-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

As the @jumpa mentioned, you're re-using the dictionary name as another variable.

Try this update:

```
for state, abbrev in list(states.items()):
    print(f'the {state} is abbreviated as {abbrev}')
print(states)
print(cities)    
#print every city and states
for abbrev, city in list(cities.items()):
    print(f'the {abbrev} state has {city} city')
print(f'2. {states}')
print(f'3. {cities}')
# now lets access both the states and cities dictionaries
for state, abbrev in list(states.items()):
    print(f' the {state} state is abbreviated as {abbrev}')
    print(f' and has the city {cities[abbrev]}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lottty lot. That solved it. So here, basically i reused the dictionary name as a loop variable  scrolling through the list variable and at the end of the loop, the dictionary ends up being a string of the last item on the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in these lines:

```
for abbrev, cities in list(cities.items()):
    print(f'the {abbrev} state has {cities} city')
```

You are overriding the original value for `cities` variable. And, it will hold the last value in the loop given by `cities.items()`

Simply use another variable in your loop. Your code will look like as such:

```
for state, abbrv in list(states.items()):
    print(f'the {states} is abbreviated as {abbrv}')
print(states)
print(cities)    
#print every city and states
for abbr, city in list(cities.items()):
    print(f'the {abbr} state has {city} city')
print(f'2. {states}')
print(f'3. {cities}')
# now lets access both the states and cities dictionaries
for state, abbrv in states.items():
    print(f' the {states} state is abbreviated as {abbrv}')
    print(f' and has the city {cities[abbrv]}')
```

Answer (score -2):

If you check line no. 34 the quote type `` isn't accepted in python. Instead you should be using '' or " " type of quotes.
Also in the loop **for states, abbrev in list(state`enter code here`s.items())**  make it **for states, abbrev in list(states.items())**

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem, just an unfortunate typo that has to do with SO's goofy code editor autosuggestion for code blocks.